# Regex for minimum number of characters

Tags: regex

I created this regular expression to validate names:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\,]+.\*?$
```

Is there a way add the minimum number of characters?

I know we can use `{x,}`, but I cannot make it work.

Comment: Re: "I know we can use {x,} but I cannot make it work": Can you post what you tried? Because there's no reason that shouldn't work, unless you're using a regex engine that doesn't support that notation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{x,}` should be used instead of `+` here...

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,-]{5,}
```

But this would mean, "at least 5 characters in the beginning match those from the character class, and then anything...

If you write it like this (almost your original - just with {5,} instead of +):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\,]{5,}.\*?$
```

This means "at least 5 characters in the beginning match those from the character class, and any *one* character, and then optionally an asterisk, and that should be the end of it".

Comment: Hm. Not sure i got the problem right ;) so, if you want to ensure the **total** length of at least x characters, follow F.J`s advice ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the beginning of the regex to make sure the total number of characters is at least your minimum.  For example, if your minimum is 8 characters:

```
^(?=.{8,})[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-,]+.\*?$
```

Also, you don't need to escape the comma.

Comment: @code-gijoe this should work in Java too, but it depends on the regexp engine if the lookaround features are supported